# Collection Interface Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListDemo{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Object> arl=new ArrayList<Object>();
    Integer i1=new Integer(10);
    Integer i2=new Integer(20);
    Integer i3=new Integer(30);
    Integer i4=new Integer(40);

arl.add(i1);
arl.add(i2);
arl.add(s1);
System.out.println("The content of arraylist is: " + arl);
System.out.println("The size of an arraylist is: " + arl.size());
```

Here is a simple arrayList program. 
ArrayList extends AbstractList and implements List, Cloneable, Serializable.

Here my question is: Is it not necessary to implement all the methods present in above mentioned interface (List, Cloneable, Serializable) by arrayList class (ArrayListDemo).

Comment: In your case, it isn't necessary to implement anything in the ArrayListDemo because it doesn't extend or implement any class or interface at all. But I probably got your question wrong, please clarify it.

Comment: It isn't, if you override an abstract sub-class or implementation, you don't need to override all, or even any methods.

Answer (score 3):

It is, unless your class extends another class which already supplies those methods, or your class is an abstract class. For example:

```
interface Foo {
    void bar();
    void baz();
}

class Superclass {
    public void bar() {}
}

class Subclass extends Superclass implements Foo {
    // We need to implement baz, but bar is okay already
    @Override public void baz() {}
}

abstract class AbstractClass implements Foo {
    // No need to do anything... a subclass will need
    // to implement both bar and baz though
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With something like

```
class C implements Collection {...}
```

you must implement all methods, did you try? You can use

```
class C extends AbstractCollection {...}
```

and get a lot of methods implemented.

Answer (score 3):

`ArraylistDemo` is not **extending** `arraylist`, it is just using one. As `ArrayList` allready implements those interfaces, you do not need to do so yourself.

Comment: He is not claiming that. He is saying *"ArrayList extends AbstractList"*

Comment: it does, but it is not a class he implemented ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html ). the last sentence is hard-ish to understand but the fact that "arraylistdemo" is there in brackets i assumed he wants to implement them there. So there is no need to implement those functions in HIS class, because they are allready in arralyist.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` only has to implement the methods which aren't already present in `AbstractList`. So long as the methods are available, it doesn't matter whether they come from `ArrayList` itself or one of its superclasses.

It's not clear to me what you mean by "by arrayList class (ArrayListDemo)" though. `ArrayListDemo` itself doesn't implement the interfaces or extend `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all, because ArrayListDemo does'nt extend or implement any class (Object of course). It only uses ArrayList as a local variable type. And ArrayList is full implemented.

Comment: He is not claiming that. He is saying *"ArrayList extends AbstractList"*

Answer (score 0):

It is, unless your implementation is only partial (`abstract class`). Then the remaining interface methods have to be implemented by the (concrete) class that extends the abstract class.

Finally, *all* interface methods *need* an implementation, otherwise the compiler *will* complain.